# All Plugins Showing "Not Installed" After Promoting Changes From Dev to Stage Environments

Tags: plugin-development, plugins, multi-environment, environmentvariables, dashboard-widgets

We are using the custom exec widget to move the codebase, backend fields, section creations, and images from one environment to another.

We have Dev, Stage, and Production environments. After completing the development work in the Dev environment we push the custom exec widget to move codebase from Dev to Stage, Stage to Prod, and vice versa. It was working fine previously but yesterday we faced some issues in the Dev environment.

After pushed the exec widget some of the plugins are uninstalled automatically and the site is not working.

Steps to Reproduce:-

- Make changes in the Dev environment like fields creation or codebase changes in the GIT repo
- Push Exec widget from Backend
- Wait for 2 mins then errors occurred

Error:-
We have used the Navigation plugin in the header section.

> Twig Runtime Error – Twig\Error\RuntimeError
> Calling unknown method: craft\web\twig\variables\CraftVariable::navigation()

Versions of Craft CMS & PHP:-

- PHP version 7.4.16
- OS version Linux 3.10.0-1160.31.1.el7.x86_64
- Database driver & version PostgreSQL 12.7
- Image driver & version Imagick 3.4.4 (ImageMagick 6.9.12-15)
- Craft edition & version Craft Pro 3.7.10

The following plugins are uninstalled after we pushed the exec widget.

- Agnostic Fetch - 2.0.4
- AsyncQueue - 2.3.0
- Eager Beaver - 1.0.4
- Element API - 2.7.0
- Enupal Snapshot - 1.2.8
- Exec Widget - 1.0.0
- Feed Me - 4.4.0
- Guest Entries - 2.4.0
- ImageOptimize - 1.6.3
- Image Resizer - 2.1.0
- Navigation - 1.4.20
- Picture - 2.2.2
- Redactor - 2.8.8
- Redirect Manager - 1.1.1
- SEOmatic - 3.4.2
- Super Table - 2.6.8
- Typed link field - 1.0.25
- Wordsmith - 3.3.0.1

Expected result:

After pushing the exec widget all the codebase changes, fields, sections are moved to the Staging environment.

We tried to figure out what causing the issue but unfortunately, we couldn't. So could you please help us to resolve this issue?

Comment: What exactly are you using the exec plugin for in your workflow? Why not just [propagate config changes through git](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/project-config.html#propagating-changes)? The project config includes the list of installed plugins in the `config/project/project.yaml` file. Probably something went something wrong in your deployment pipeline which lead to an older config file being applied. If an installed plugin is not listed in the `project.yaml` during the `project-config/apply` step, Craft will uninstall it automatically …

Answer (score 1):

> "After pushing the exec widget all the codebase changes, fields, sections are moved to the Staging environment."

You skipped a step...

Assuming you are properly using Project Config, you'll want to run `craft up` after deploying your files.